# Matplotlib - Grouping Dataframe values and adding them to the X Axis within a certain range

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

please bear with me as I'm finding it difficult to even explain it.

I'm trying to group a column of numbers from a dataframe, example grouping:

-0.239361
-0.013423
0.013225
-0.150482

I then want to create line plots for them horizontally across the x axis, with a range of 1-10, the highest number (in this example 0.013225)  should go to 10 and the lowest number (-0.239361) should go to 1. With the other 2 numbers matching where they would go inbetween min and max.

The logic involved is doing my head in, please help!

Cheers

Here is a bad paint picture explaining the graph I'm looking for

[image]

Comment: are the numbers in a Series?

Comment: Hey Pablo, yes that's correct

Answer (score 2):

Basically, you want to do an "interplolation". You can use [`scipy.interpolate.interp1d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp1d.html):

```
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#I assume your data is in a pandas Series named ser
inter = interp1d([ser.min(), ser.max()], [1,10])
y = range(1,5)

plt.barh(y, inter(ser))
plt.yticks(y)
plt.show()
```

[image]